# remote machine/cloud application storage for running software

Tags: linux, storage, application, cloud

I don't have a large SSD disk and every now and then I want to run a VM and I run out of storage, I want to run a nodejs project that for some reason needs an insane amount of storage for npm modules, or I want to test something and I need to install Maven/JDK and all similarly large packages.

Is there a way we deal with applications on the cloud in a similar way we deal with files on the cloud? Maybe only install or use a program when it is needed without removing and installing every time?

Edit:  Suppose I want to run a haskell code and I need to install the haskell compiler but I do not have any space left on storage. The way I'm thinking of resolving this is one of two solutions. 1) The code will run in a remote machine and I get back the result. 2) An already installed application, maybe a program that I haven't used in a while, get pushed out of disk to make space for the haskell compiler to run the code. That pushed/kicked application would only make it back when there is sufficient space for it or if I want to run something using that application.

I'm looking to make all of this very seamless, either of the scenarios or maybe a scenario 3 that solves this issue of no space in disk for applications.

Comment: What are you asking here? How to create a VM in "the cloud"?

Comment: No, not really. Is it possible to make application storage elastic in a similar way as files storage. The title is a bit stupid, I now realize. But imagine I want to run a haskell script but I don't have haskell in my machine. Can I seamlessly run it on my machine and it will run on the cloud and come back with no break in UX? The other solution is actually bringing in haskell at the moment via a large download (assuming it was off because it was rarely used on my machine).

Comment: I can't parse `run it on my machine and it will run on the cloud`; perhaps you could edit the Question to spell out an example?

Comment: @Jeff, I expanded a bit on it in the question. Thanks for your attention.